# Emacs `t` letter at end of code

Tags: emacs, elisp

What is the `t` letter at the end of code is for ?

like here:

```
(load-theme 'seti t)
```

and here:

```
(global-linum-mode t)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Emacs Lisp, non-nil value is treated as `true`, however, `t` is the preferred way to represent the truth value `true`. Perhaps you might be got the same result if you put `1` or `hello` instead of `t`.

Perhaps you want to read [1.3.2 nil and t](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/nil-and-t.html)

Comment: +1 for linking to the manual. You might also want to summarize some of that info here, to make your answer more complete. The real information in your answer is just a link, and link-only answers are discouraged here. Consider providing a little info about truth values in Lisp.

Comment: @Drew Yes, you're right. I added some more information.